# Iterative Post of a form in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation where I need to post a form from my "view" multiple times but on a single click of the submit button.

In the view model I have a "List" along with other fields. I want to POST the form for each different value in the list-type property of the model and append the result on each response to a div.

Let Say my Model is:

public class VMSendSMS
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }, 
        public IList Mobile { get; set; }
    }

Now, I want to post the form as many times as there are items in "IList Mobile".

I am new in this field so Please reply as simple as possible if there exist any solution.

Comment: It's doubtful you'll get many replies to this - your objectives aren't clear at all. Do you have any existing code to show what you have / have tried so far? I "guess" that if you want to POST to multiple sources then you can do this with multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: I want to post form values to the same controller action but each time withe different values.

Comment: How are you collecting these "different values"?  Will they be input by a user or are you performing some logic on them?  If you're performing logic then you might be able to use some kind of recursion on your controller, alternatively Javascript (specifically AJAX) is the way to go.

Comment: I am assuming you want to POST the data without refreshing the page? if thats the case you will have to use AJAX. Also I am not quite sure doing multiple POST is the right solution. Since you are posting to the same location I would send all fields to the controller via AJAX and return a JSON object with the results for the different divs. Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for your time.. I am fetching the data from database. I have different groups of our clients. The user select a group from dropdown and write a message in a text area and on clicking the send button the content of the textarea is send to each client in the group by sms on their mobile. I want to show some feedback of each sms as it is sent.

Comment: Sending post is working fine but with it I can only receive one response at the end when sms is sent to all the clients in the group. But i want to print success/unsuccess when sms is sent to each group member. AJAX seems to be the right option as you mentioned but I am not clear oabout the sentax.

Comment: You don't need to send multiple posts to achieve that.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree if you are attempting multiple posts, the entire form should be posted once and you should be looking into polling for statuses of the sms sends.

Answer (score -1):

Search for

```
$.when.apply("").done()
```

Comment: Your answer is about as descriptive as the question, at least make some effort.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul instead of wasting time for writing this comment and downmarking the answer you should make some effort to solve this ques. from my hint.